# Define column name as another name in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I have a query as below:

```
SELECT value
    FROM table
    WHERE ((col1+col2+col3)/col4) > 4
    AND ((col1+col2+col3)/col4) < 5
UNION ALL
SELECT value
    FROM table
    WHERE ((col1+col2+col3)/col4) > 3
    AND ((col1+col2+col3)/col4) < 4
```

I'd like to define `((col1+col2+col3)/col4)` as some name, so if I want to change the conditions of the SQL query (eg. maybe I'd like it to be `((col1+col2-col3)*col4)` instead), I don't need to go through the entire text of the SQL query and change every line.

```
DEFINE ((col1+col2+col3)/col4) AS var
SELECT value
    FROM table
    WHERE var > 4
    AND var < 5
UNION ALL
SELECT value
    FROM table
    WHERE var > 3
    AND var < 4
```

Only one line needs to be altered instead of four in this example. It's easier to read and maintain.

Comment: What database are you using? Please tag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the `union all` before the definition:

```
SELECT ((col1+col2+col3)/col4) as value
FROM ((SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
       FROM table1
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
       FROM table2
      )
     ) t
HAVING value > 4 and value < 5
```

This use of the `having` clause is specific to MySQL.  You would need another subquery or CTE for another database.

Answer (score 2):

```
   SELECT tt.value FROM 
   (SELECT ((t.col1+t.col2+t.col3)/t.col4) as value
      FROM ((SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
               FROM #Temp
            ) UNION ALL
            (SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
               FROM #Temp
            )

           ) t)tt
GROUP BY tt.value
HAVING tt.value > 4 and tt.value < 5
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL:

> "User variables are intended to provide data values. They cannot be
>   used directly in an SQL statement as an identifier or as part of an
>   identifier, such as in contexts where a table or database name is
>   expected, or as a reserved word such as SELECT. This is true even if
>   the variable is quoted[...]"

Link:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

That said, you may construct and execute the query as follows:

```
SET @var=((col1+col2+col3)/col4);
SET @s=CONCAT("SELECT value FROM table WHERE ", @var," > 4 AND ", @var,
" < 5 UNION ALL SELECT value FROM table WHERE ", @var," > 3 AND ", @var,
" < 4");
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

However, this probably defeats the purpose of making it easier to read or maintain.